# С чего начать в написании веб-приложения?

Tags: python

Мне необходимо написать веб-приложение "фотосайт" на `python`, используя `pylons`. Кто-нибудь может мне показать пример кода. И с чего вообще начать?

СУБД – `postgreSQL`

Базовые функциональные требования :

1. Создание альбомов
2. Загрузка фотографий
3. Просмотр содержимого альбома (списка фотографий)
4. Просмотр отделной фотографии

Дополнительные функциональные требования:

1. Удаление альбома и фотографий;
2. Редактирование метаданных альбома и фотографии
3. Использование постраничной навигации при просмторе льбома( по умолчанию 10 фотографий на страницу)
4. Удаление фотографии без перезагрузки страницы (Ajax), при просмотре содержимого альбома
5. Авторизация/регистрация пользователей

Comment: Похоже на тестовое задание при приёме на работу... Я угадал?

Answer (score 2):

Вот вам [галерея на пилонах/пирамиде](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyGall/0.9.1). Качайте, изучайте код.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы посоветовал продумать сначала всё на листочке:
 1. Продумать функционал.
 2. Описать таблицы в БД.
 3. Выполнить весь функционал, без применения стилей. Просто поместить весь "вывод" в диваны.
 4. Натянуть вёрстку на функционал.

Всегда следую именно этому порядку, при разработке back-end.  
Если ведётся front-end, то конечно лучше будет продумать иерархию DOM, выполнить вёрстку и потом начинать добавлять функционал.